# How to correctly use SerialPort.DiscardInBuffer?

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I've written an application which reads from a serial device at a very fast rate. The serial port object however, fails to fire the [DataReceived](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived) event after about 20 min of continuous operation. Disconnecting and reconnecting the serial programmatically allows the event to work again but for only another 20 min.

I tried using [DiscardInBuffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.discardinbuffer) after every [DataReceived](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived) event and this has appeared to have solved the problem. But the method consumes a lot of cpu time and is degrading the performance of the application. MSDN mentions that the method "Discards data from the serial driver's receive buffer.", but fails to suggest when it should be used.

When and how should [DiscardInBuffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.discardinbuffer) be used, and am I using it in the correct context for my particular problem ?

Edit:

After implementing the [ErrorReceived](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.errorreceived) event, the event data returned indicated the event type was an [RXOver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialerror).

Comment: Are you listening to the ErrorReceived event? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.errorreceived.aspx

Comment: No I'm not. What should I be looking out for in the ErrorReceived event ?

Answer (score 1):

After more investigations, it appears my problem was more a fundamental issue. Since the data was flooding in at a hot pace, the SerialPort buffer needed to be cleared or processed continuously to prevent the "RXOver" error. I achieved this by reading into another buffer during the `DataReceived` event and processed it in another separate thread.

From my understanding the `DiscardInBuffer` should only be used selectively to clear the contents of the ports for initialisation purposes, such as before opening a port. The process of clearing the driver buffer does take some time to complete and therefore should be used wisely in a performance orientated application.

Comment: You said:such as before opening a port. Why before, you receive data and run once, so I think it should be after. Is this idea correct? Thank you~

Comment: @steeppham If you try to discard the buffers before the port has been opened, you get an exception "The port is closed.". The port needs to be open in order to call the discard methods.

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas come to mind. The first (horrible) idea: call `DiscardInBuffer` every 15 to 20 minutes instead of after every `DataReceived` event. The second (somewhat better) idea: call `DiscardInBuffer` when you receive the `ErrorReceived` event, which you should be handling.

Comment: Gave your idea a try, and it appeared to had alleviate the problem after receiving the "RXOver" message error.